# MongoDB .NET select only max datetime items distinct by field

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

There are many elements in collection

```cs
public class ElementItemValue
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public Guid ElementItemId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
'1', '2016-01-01', 'AA', '0'
'2', '2016-01-02', 'AA', '1'
'3', '2016-01-01', 'BB', '0'
'4', '2016-01-02', 'BB', '2'
'5', '2016-01-01', 'CC', '0'
'6', '2016-01-02', 'CC', '3'
```

How with one linq query get rows 2,4,5 (values 1,2,3)

P.S. I write mongodb query

```
db
.getCollection('ElementItemValues')
.aggregate(
{
     $group: { _id: '$ElementItemId'
         , Id: { $last: '$_id'}
         , Value: { $last: '$Value'}
    }
})
```

a) is correct?

b) is optimal?

Comment: I think you mean something like `all.Where(w=> w.Updated == all.Max(f => f.Updated))` ;).

Comment: @shA.t its query run in mongo or load all collection to client?

Comment: it's linq in c# as you tagged your question and yes it needs to load all collections as `all` - if you need a Mongo query remove those tags ;).